# I can't open a server with rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails, in some other questions I read sometimes it's a problem with the Webrick server.

I think this time it has to do with the directory path. I am learning with an online course, so I think I need to stay with Webrick, if possible! My Rails version is `5.0.0.1`

When I try to open a new server, using the command `rails server` this message appears:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]  # Skip Action Mailer files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                    # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]    # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                    # Skip test files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change directory into the path of your application and then start the server.

If you haven't created an app yet, you need to do that first using `rails new nameofapp`

To change directory do this by running `cd path/path/app` and change the path to the correct path, and the app to the correct app name.

Then run `rails server` or `rails s` to start the server and go to http://localhost:3000 in your browser